# How can I Get FB Event Venue Struct values using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I Get FB Event Venue Struct values using FQL in the same Event Query :
Based on Event FB Documentation .. venue is a struct property but i can't access its members like street,city,state,country,zip,latitude,longitude,id
[FB Event Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event)

By Using the query below i can't access venue values ..

```
SELECT name,description, start_time,end_time, venue.street,venue.city,venue.country,venue.zip, venue.latitude,venue.longitude, venue.id, venue.name, venue.located_in
FROM event WHERE eid =296244733844027
```

[FQL Query Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20name,description,%20start_time,end_time,%20venue.street,venue.city,venue.country,venue.zip,%20venue.latitude,venue.longitude,%20venue.id,%20venue.name,%20venue.located_in%0AFROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20=296244733844027)

**so any suggestions about how to get Venue Values in FB Event Query using FQL**

Answer (score 0):

It's returned in the json ... as follows for example ...

{
  "data": 
   [
     {
      "name": "Outdoor Movie Night & BBQ @ the Chambers!", 
      "description": "Party!!!", 
      "start_time": "2013-06-22T19:00:00-0700", 
      "end_time": null, 
      "venue": {
        "name": "000 0th Ave W, Seattle"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Also, sometimes you might only get the `id` in the venue, which is kind of a bug by design of Facebook